# Multiple user roles in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, roles

I am building an inventory management application with four different user types: admin, employee, manufacturer, transporter.  I haven't started coding yet, but this is what I'm thinking.. Manufacturers and transporters are related with has_many :through many-to-many association with products as follows:

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :transporters, :through => :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :manufacturer
 belongs_to :transporter
end

class Transporter < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :manufacturers, :through => :products
end
```

All four user types will be able to login, but they will have different permissions and views, etc.  I don't think I can put them in the same table (Users), however, because they will have different requirements, ie: vendors and manufacturers must have a billing address and contact info (through validations), but admins and employees should not have these fields.

If possible, I would like to have a single login screen as opposed to 4 different screens.

I'm not asking for the exact code to build this, but I'm having trouble determining the best way to make it happen.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your basic approach seems reasonable. I would advise you to make a base class of User and use STI for specific User types, for instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Manufacturer < User
 has_many :products
 has_many :transporters, :through => :products
end
```

...etc. This way if there's ever the need to aggregate multiple user types into one relationship regardless of type, you have one table to describe Users in general. This is a fairly common approach.

Depending on how much access different users will have to the system, you may want to look at a Role Management gem like [Declarative Authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  How would the database tables be set up for this, with a base class of User and STI for specific User types?  I'm really, really new to rails :)

Comment: You'll only have a 'users' table in the db. STI/Single Table Inheritance uses a 'type' field in a base table (in this case 'users') to distinguish between subtypes of the base class. You need to add this field in a migration. Then all attributes for all subtypes of the base class will be kept in the users table, even though many of them won't be used by specific instances/rows. This is the tradeoff using the STI pattern -- you may have a number of null fields for unused attributes, depending on how many subtype-specific attributes there are.

Answer (score 5):

For Multiple user systems, generally preferred ways are - use of role model or STI. If your users can have multiple roles at same time, like single user being Manufacturer and transporter, then Role base system would be good solution. If users role is fixed, then i think you should go with STI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a User model, Address model, ContactInfo model, etc. You should NOT have those kinds of fields in the User model. Normalize the database. Have a FK in each of those other classes to User.id.

If you MUST keep them separate, then normalize logins and make it polymorphic to reference its owner (manufacturer, employee, etc)

Comment: Weeeelll...maybe. Having an addresses table is certainly normalized, but in the real world many times it's overkill, and in fact more often than not even the most hard-core normalization freaks will admit that something like an address -- which in most cases amounts to nothing more than a varchar field -- doesn't need to be normalized into its own table with all the overhead that incurs. Do you really want an SQL join hit for ever users query? Not very performant for such a simple operation. So much depends on the domain, and whether addresses are truly complex and reusable, etc.

Comment: @Dave Sims - I completely, respectfully disagree. In today's world, we need as much information as possible. Normalization (especially with addresses) allows future expansion - we can allow a user to have multiple addresses (home and work for example). And, whether SELECT * returns 10 columns or JOIN returns 10 columns, it doesn't matter (like the overhead is literally insignificant for even incredibly large datasets). Furthermore, you won't ALWAYS show an address with a user, so why would you have it in the users table? It's a separate object

Comment: @Dave Sims - (con't). I look at it this way. I HAVE a first name, I HAVE a last name. I also HAVE an addresses. I DONT HAVE an address_line_1 and address_line_2, zip..., an address HAS an address_line_1, 2..zip, etc. For me, it just makes WAY more sense to have these things separate. Can you have a user without an address? do you REALLY want to restrict access to your site if someone is homeless? I'm being over-the-top, but I think you'll see why normalization is important.

Comment: @seth.vargo: That's a good statement of the well-known benefits of normalization, but you have to also acknowledge those benefits come at a cost that might not make sense for every app. Over-normalization can be a case of early optimization. In 'today's world', we've seen that having a fk for every bit of related data can be as much a liability as a benefit. The rise of frameworks like Mongo, et al, show that for many apps and domains normalization is not the primary concern, performance is, where data can be expressed in simple tree structures rather than complex relational structures.

Comment: @seth.vargo: As for your assertion about the performance of joins -- um, have you ever actually had to optimize a real world production query? One of the first rules of optimization is to limit the number of tables you join on (where possible), and I assure you that in 'today's world' this is far from an insignificant concern. As to your poor homeless guy -- dude, I have no idea what normalization has to do with that. You can have a required/non-required field or a required/non-required fk/pkid, enforced at the schema level, the application level, or both.

Comment: @seth.vargo: So, I agree to a point, and particularly in the OP's stated domain, yes, probably necessary to split out into an address table, as it seems the kind of domain that would have complex addresses that would be reused by more than one entity. All things being equal, start with a normalized schema and flatten/denormalize as needed. But this is not an absolute rule. There are conceivable cases where performance might trump the data reuse/resilience provided by normalization.

Comment: In my very humle opinion: There is a clear benefit to having a normalized database involving refactoring, while key-value storage, like MongoDB would do, can often be taken care of with caching (theoretically -- you can "flatten" your joins in production with a cache).  Relational databases have much more power when normalized.  If you care about your app and it's organization long-term you're better off normalizing your database.  If you follow conventions with normalizing (and always do it) it isn't really over-optimizing too soon.